# Error inicio de sesión en 2 aplicaciones asp net mvc en el mismo servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Tengo 2 aplicaciones aspnet mvc 5 corriendo en el mismo servidor, ej: http://localhost:6869 y  http://localhost:6870, abro las paginas de inicio de sesión al mismo tiempo, trato de loguearme en la primera y todo bien, cuando me quiero loguear en la segunda me da el siguiente error. o si no, inicio sesión en la segunda pero me desloguea de la primera.

Error!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita la pregunta y muestra el código del inició de sesión para  ayudarte

Comment: el problema es el siguiente, cuando abro una aplicación manda el antiforgerytoken y cuando abro la segunda manda otro token, cuando me logueo en 1 no hay problema, el problema esta cuando me quiero loguear en la segunda, el token que tiene no es valido, probe agregando a cada aplicacion de manera estática el validationkey y machinekey y nada.

Comment: Hola. Puedes mostrar el `web.config` de cada aplicación? Deberían tener ambos la misma clave de `<machineKey 
  validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" [String]
  decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" [String]
  validation="SHA1" [SHA1 | MD5 | 3DES | AES]
  decryption="Auto" [Auto | DES | 3DES | AES]
/>`

Comment: estas asignando el mismo Application pool para ambos sitios ?

Comment: tienen pool distintos , y tengo en localsystem el identity

Comment: le genere un machine key a cada aplicación y no me muestra el error, pero me desloguea de la otra aplicación donde ya estoy logueado.